# Laravel session flash not working for auth routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

When there is a CSRF token mismatch, I'm trying to redirect back to the login form with a helpful message. To do this, I added the following to `Exceptions\Handler`:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        return redirect('/')->withErrors([
            'token_mismatch' => trans('auth.token_mismatch')
        ]);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

However, the message never makes it to the `$errors` variable in the view:

```
@if (count($errors))
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable margin5">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        {{ $errors->first() }}
    </div>
@endif
```

My `Http\Kernel` looks good, as far as I can tell:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

My `web.php` file contains Laravel 5.3 default `Auth::routes();` for handling the login.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just debugging here. Can you try a `redirect()->back()->withErrors()` and change your `@if (count($errors))` to `@if($errors->any())` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @EddyTheDove I actually did a `dd($errors)` and it was an empty `MessageBag`. I did an Xdebug trace into `withErrors()` which showed that the `errors` key was being assigned the expected message, but it isn't retrievable later with the session.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by changing:

```
return redirect('/')->withErrors([
    'token_mismatch' => trans('auth.token_mismatch', ['domain' => config('session.domain')])
]);
```

...to:

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
    'token_mismatch' => trans('auth.token_mismatch', ['domain' => config('session.domain')])
]);
```